# Why does sbt keep throwing this error whenever I run it?

Tags: scala, sbt

Running any sbt command throws a java error -

"The java installation you have is not up to date
requires at least version 1.6+, you have
version 1.8"

This is after the last sbt update . I am unable to check the current sbt version because I run into the above mentioned error on running sbt sbt-version.

Comment: Which sbt version did you have before the update? How did you update?

Comment: I probably had 0.13 . It updated automatically from the ppa https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian when running apt update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue.
In my error output the first line is

`/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash: line 207: bc: command not found`

followed by your java error message

installing `bc` solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

just add bc installation `sudo apt install bc` it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed and sbt no longer requires bc to be installed.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please use the comments section for these messages.